# PHP Router / .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to implement the router class JREAM http://jream.com/lab/route

Files are at https://bitbucket.org/JREAM/route/src

Everything seems to be working fine except for some 301 redirects we have on the site.

If I do

```
Redirect 301 /free http://www.domain.com/join/
```

It redirects to http://www.domain.com/join/?uri=free and breaks.

Why would the 301 redirects not just redirect it before the router kicks in?

---

This was the origial .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I just added

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)free /join/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

And it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Post the full `.htaccess` file, there are clearly other rules interfering.

Comment: Please use "edit post" next time, don't use "answer" to provide additional information about you problem.